# unable to download videos in ubuntu using youtube-dl

Tags: python, 22.04, youtube, youtube-dl

Whenever I try to download videos using the youtube-dl, I get an error:

usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using do you have python installed ?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS  and yes python is installed

Answer (score 0):

Running
sudo apt install python-is-python3

Does the trick